# using replace for a column of a pandas df TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

How should I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd                                                                        

csv_file = 'sample.csv'                                                                    
count = 1                                                                                  
my_filtered_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=['subDirectory_filePath', 'expression'])   

emotion_map = { '0':'6', '1':'3', '2':'4', '3':'5', '4':'2', '5':'1', '6':'0'}             

my_filtered_csv['expression'] = my_filtered_csv['expression'].replace(emotion_map)         

print(my_filtered_csv)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mona/CS585/project/affnet/emotion_map.py", line 11, in <module>
    my_filtered_csv['expression'] = my_filtered_csv['expression'].replace(emotion_map)
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3836, in replace
    limit=limit, regex=regex)
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3885, in replace
    regex=regex)
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3259, in replace_list
    masks = [comp(s) for i, s in enumerate(src_list)]
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3259, in <listcomp>
    masks = [comp(s) for i, s in enumerate(src_list)]
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3247, in comp
    return _maybe_compare(values, getattr(s, 'asm8', s), operator.eq)
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4619, in _maybe_compare
    raise TypeError("Cannot compare types %r and %r" % tuple(type_names))
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

A few lines of the csv file looks like:

```
,subDirectory_filePath,expression
0,689/737db2483489148d783ef278f43f486c0a97e140fc4b6b61b84363ca.jpg,1
1,392/c4db2f9b7e4b422d14b6e038f0cdc3ecee239b55326e9181ee4520f9.jpg,0
2,468/21772b68dc8c2a11678c8739eca33adb6ccc658600e4da2224080603.jpg,0
3,944/06e9ae8d3b240eb68fa60534783eacafce2def60a86042f9b7d59544.jpg,1
4,993/02e06ee5521958b4042dd73abb444220609d96f57b1689abbe87c024.jpg,8
5,979/f675c6a88cdef99a6d8b0261741217a0319387fcf1571a174f99ac81.jpg,6
6,637/94b769d8e880cbbea8eaa1350cb8c094a03d27f9fef44e1f4c0fb2ae.jpg,9
7,997/b81f843f08ce3bb0c48b270dc58d2ab8bf5bea3e2262e50bbcadbec2.jpg,6
8,358/21a32dd1c1ecd57d3e8964621c911df1c0b3348a4ae5203b4a243230.JPG,9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the emotion_map to the following fixed the problem:

```
emotion_map = { 0:6, 1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 4:2, 5:1, 6:0}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution saved my day! Never really considered the dictionary might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another possiblity which can also create this error is:
you have already run this code once and the data is already replaced.

To solve this problem, you can go back and load the data set again